# How to fix undefined variable error in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I'm very new to this so sincere apologies if this is a silly question!

I have two tables in my database - 'users' and 'departments'. I am trying to assign a 'user' to a 'department' as a department manager and storing their user_id in the department table.

What I want to do is be able to choose from a dropdown of users in the create department form, but I keep getting the error below:

Undefined variable: users (View: /home/vagrant/code/PortfolioManager/resources/views/admin/departments/index.blade.php)

Would anyone have any idea where I am going wrong? I have been trying to resolve this for 2 days.

My Department Model code is below:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Department extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'user_id'
        ];

        public function user(){

            return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        }
    }
```

My Controller is here also:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Department;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreDepartmentRequest;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class AdminDepartmentsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $departments = Department::all();

        return view('admin.departments.index', compact('departments'));
    }


    public function create()
    {
        $users = User::lists('name', 'id')->all();
        return view('admin.departments.index', compact('users'));
    }


    public function store(StoreDepartmentRequest $request)
    {
        Department::create($request->all());

        return redirect('admin.departments.index');
    }
```

My index.blade page is here:

```
<h1>Departments</h1>

<div class="col-sm-6">

    {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'AdminDepartmentsController@store']) !!}

    {{--Name field which is displayed empty--}}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name', 'Department Name:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('user_id', 'Department Manager:') !!}
        {!! Form::select('user_id', ['' => 'Choose Department Manager'] + $users, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Create Business Department', ['class'=>'btn-btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}


</div>
```

Comment: when you see this error write return $variable or dd($variable) after you get them...for ex. here: after $users = User::lists('name', 'id')->all();  write return $users; and you see your eloquent results

Answer (score 0):

Your create method is wrong...write below code:

```
public function create()
{
    $users = User::latest()->get();
    return view('admin.departments.index', compact('users'));
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and am still getting the same error. I also tried writing return $users in the create method but am still getting the exact same error

Comment: try dd($users); instead of return $users; in create method.  what you see now?

Comment: Updated to dd($users) and still getting the same

Comment: @RuthLavelle are your sure you have this error in this method and controller? because dd() not show this error

Comment: I'm only learning so not entirely sure, but if I comment out this section of index.blade.php, I am able to load the page in my browser without any errors: {{--}} <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('user_id', 'Department Manager:') !!}
            {!! Form::select('user_id', ['' => 'Choose Department Manager'] + $users, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>--}}

Comment: @RuthLavelle when you write dd($users)l before return view('admin.departments.index', compact('users'));   It just show $users to you and don't run new line (means: return view.......)

Comment: public function create()
{
    $users = User::latest()->get();
    dd($users);
}

Comment: Yes have done that and then also commented out the return view. I am still getting the same error. This is what I have now: public function create()
    {
        $users = User::latest()->get();
        dd($users);
        return view('admin.departments.index', compact('users'));
    }

Comment: Also ran this, but still getting the same error: public function create()
    {
        $users = User::latest()->get();
        dd($users);
        //return view('admin.departments.index', compact('users'));
    }